# Intelligencia UrlRewriter Error "Item has already been added"

Tags: urlrewriter.net

I am getting error " Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'RewritingXtoY'  Key being added: 'RewritingXtoY' ".

Here is a stack trace :

> at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue,
>   Boolean add)   at
>   Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Utilities.MessageProvider.FormatString(Message
>   message, Object[] args)   at
>   Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterEngine.Rewrite()   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

It is working well on localhost,but found error on production.There is no duplicate url rule in web.config file.

Any help?

Comment: I am getting the same error, except with the key 'ProductName'

Comment: Me too with 'ProductName', no idea why, this string does not appear in my project anywhere so it must be in the Intelligencia code somewhere, possibly some testing code left in there when the DLL went to production?